# JFace : Adding images to a table viewer is creating an issue

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

I have a table viewer with 5 columns. In the 1st column I check some conditions and add an image and the rest of the columns will have text, But when I try to add the image and then add the rest of the columns with text then the 2nd column's text sits right beside the image in the 1st column. Here's my sample code snippet :

```
TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
if(condition) {
item.setImage(image);
}
else {
item.setImage(image);
}
item.setText(new String[]{"street", "city","state","Zip Code"});
```

Problem is that the string "street" sits right beside the image in the 1st column itself but I want the string "street" in the second column and the rest of the strings in the subsequent columns. What am I doing wrong here? How do I add table items from the 2nd column?

Answer (score 0):

Each column in the table can have both an image and text.

Calling `item.setImage(image)` sets the image for the first column.

Calling `item.setText(String [])` sets the text for each column starting at the first column. So your "street" goes next to the image.

If you don't want text in the first column then set the text for that column to blank:

```
item.setText(new String[]{"", "street", "city", "state", "Zip Code"});
```

Update:

You can also set the text for individual columns with

```
item.setText(column, text);
```

If you are using `TableViewer` you should not be using `TableItem`, instead use the label provider and content provider.

Comment: Yes this approach can be used to resolve my issue, but I would want to know if there are any other approaches other than setting the 1st column's text to an empty string?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. Added details of some more options

Answer (score 0):

Not as clear. If you want just an image in the first colum then then just provide an empty string:

```
item.setText(new String[]{"", "street", "city","state","Zip Code"});
```

But it is not worth working with jface without using the benefits of ContentProvider and LabelProvider. So you should read some jface tutorials before doing stuff like that.

Example:

```
  TableViewer tableViewer = new TableViewer(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
      tableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

      TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumnImg = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
      tableViewerColumnImg.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider()
      {
         @Override
         public Image getImage(Object element)
         {
            Person p = (Person) element;
            return p.getImage();
         }
      });
      TableColumn tblclmnImg = tableViewerColumnImg.getColumn();
      tblclmnImg.setWidth(100);
      tblclmnImg.setText("Img");

      TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumnStreet = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
      tableViewerColumnStreet.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider()
      {
         @Override
         public String getText(Object element)
         {
            Person p = (Person) element;
            return p.getStreet();
         }
      });
      TableColumn tblclmnStreet = tableViewerColumnStreet.getColumn();
      tblclmnStreet.setWidth(100);
      tblclmnStreet.setText("Street");


      tableViewer.setInput(//set an array of persons here

);
```

Comment: Yes this approach can be used to resolve my issue, but I would want to know if there are any other approaches other than setting the 1st column's text to an empty string?

Comment: Yes as mentioned above you should consider using the Content and Labelproviders. Added an example code above.